# Java thread join()

Tags: java, multithreading, join, wait

If I have one array of 10 thread ready "to be used" and if I have something like

```
for (int i=0;i< MyThreadArray.length: i++){
MyThreadArray[i].start()
MyThreadArray.join()
}
```

If the thread #6 has a sleep() of 5 minutes, how can I run the thread #7 before the end of the #6? I have to wait for the end of the #6 or there is some instructions to run the "next thread"?

Comment: Why are you calling `join()`? Given your problem description you don't want to wait for a thread to complete, yet that is exactly what calling `join()` does. So if you don't want to wait, then don't call `join()`. Doing what you're currently doing is no better than just doing the work on the current thread.

Comment: `t.join()` waits for thread `t` to die before continuing with the loop. That's why it finishes before other threads.

Comment: For my application I have to wait the end of the n-Thread before starting the (n+1)-thread. But if I have a sleep(), I can run the (n+1)-thread.... I'm trying to do this

Comment: "You have to wait for the end of `n` thread before starting `n + 1` thread" why use threads at all then?

Comment: I try to explain better... I'm trying to perform one integration between one system no multithread(System-A) and one system multithread(System-B). In my app I run a thread after one specific event of the System-A and before continue I have to wait the end of the thread execution of the System-B. I can have one "exception": if the  thread that ran have a wait() or sleep() 
 I can run the next thread of System-B

Answer (score 4):

Use two loops. In the first one you should start all threads:

```
for (int i=0;i< MyThreadArray.length: i++){
    MyThreadArray[i].start()
}
```

This will start all of them. Afterwards, you want to wait for them to finish:

```
for (int i=0;i< MyThreadArray.length: i++){
    MyThreadArray[i].join()
    // notice    ^^^ you had a typo there
}
```

This will wait for each thread to finish before moving on.

Also, do note that this particular logic:

```
for (int i=0;i< MyThreadArray.length: i++){
    MyThreadArray[i].start()
    MyThreadArray[i].join()
}
```

is simply a worse version of **not** using parallelism, since it will wait for every single thread **sequentially**, additionally adding some overhead of starting a `Thread`.